# Apache Solr: Slave replicates 10+ times every time it polls (excessive commits?)

Tags: java, solr, replication, master-slave

We're using Apache Solr (3.1.0) to index a lot of articles written for multiple sites. We have a master/slave setup (replication config at the bottom), where server 1 indexes the articles, and server 2 replicates the index. The slave should poll the master every 60 seconds, but instead, we can see 10 to up to 75 consecutive `/replication` calls nearly every time.

Each Solr core (`${solr.core.name}` in the slave config)
 represents a different site. The `/replication` calls I see most are tied to the biggest site. One of the cores only got 1 call per minute, and I've been able to reproduce this there after calling `update?commit=true` a few times, so this leads me to think it's related to the amount of commits the master performs.

So my question is, how do I stop the Solr slave from replicating the index dozens of times and force it to replicate just once per minute? I've tried playing with the `commitReserveDuration` parameter in the master config, but I don't really see any difference.

master replication config:

```xml
 <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
   <lst name="master">
     <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
     <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
   </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```

slave replication config:

```xml
 <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
   <lst name="slave">
     <str name="masterUrl">http://${solr.master.server}/search/${solr.core.name}/replication</str>
     <str name="pollInterval">00:00:60</str>
   </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```

Comment: I would try to disable pollInterval (specify no pollInterval) and execute replication by api call triggered by a cron job. Does it help? https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=replication.png

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and calling `/replication?command=fetchindex` once triggers a lot of `/replication` calls on the master... I don't see any difference between this and keeping the pollInterval in the config. To be honest, this could be perfectly normal behaviour, but I just can't find any docs describing it.

Comment: That was just an idea to track the problem. Sorry, I can't help you further.

Comment: @Gurpreet Singh Where can I check this? I haven't seen the amount of commits anywhere yet.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Solr 6.6. Replication is happening before commit on every polling time while executing full import or its auto commit not sure, but select?q*:* is returning different data till import finishs from all master and slaves, while it works fine when I disable polling. Need any clue for same.

Comment: I left this job a few months after I asked this question and I never found the answer. Can't help you here, sorry.

Comment: Is just disabling polling an option? Since you're saying it works fine then.

Answer (score 1):

in the config you specified replication after as commit , so incase if you are issuing commit from the code very frequently  then it will trigger replication , so i would suggest to change to optimize instead of commit. This should solve your problem.  [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication#IndexReplication-ConfiguringtheReplicationHandler) is the link which gives more details on the replicationafter settings.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I change commit to optimize, the slave appears to be out of sync with the master for 5+ minutes, which is way too long. Thanks though, I'll try to find a way to call the optimization from the code and see if that works.